# Official way to denote a set of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

Is there one official way to denote a set of 2 column vectors living in $\mathbb{R}^3$? For example,

a. Does it matter if inside the set brackets they have parentheses instead of square brackets?

b. Should the column vectors be separated with their own square brackets or parentheses and divided by a comma? or could they just be put together in one square brackets/one parentheses?

Comment: a. no, b. yes, c. no.

Comment: For c. Would putting them together in one square brackets or parentheses denote a matrix?

Comment: Yes, that's right. That's different from a set of column vectors.

Comment: The set with elements $foo$ and $bar$ is $\{foo,bar\}$, so what confusion about notation do you have?

Comment: Can you add square brackets or parentheses around foo and bar?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> It's fairly conventional to use round parentheses to denote a comma-separated ordered list (a.k.a. column vector), but with columns printed _as_ columns the shape of the brackets doesn't have as strong a convention; thus $$\{(0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0)\},$$ or $$\left\{\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \end{array}\right], \left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \end{array}\right]\right\},$$ or  $$\left\{\left(\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \end{array}\right), \left(\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \end{array}\right)\right\}.$$